# Slicing pandas.Series at specified time stamps

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I am trying to slice a pandas.Series at specified time stamps. From other SO questions I got the following workflow:

```
import pandas as pd
x = ... # some time data
y = ... # some value data

lower_limit_x = pd.to_datetime(x.index) >= pd.to_datetime('2019-01-23 20:59:04')
upper_limit_x = pd.to_datetime(x.index) <= pd.to_datetime('2019-01-23 21:37:44')

lower_limit_y = pd.to_datetime(y.index) >= pd.to_datetime('2019-01-23 20:59:04')
upper_limit_y = pd.to_datetime(y.index) <= pd.to_datetime('2019-01-23 21:37:44')

mask_x = lower_limit_x & upper_limit_x
mask_y = lower_limit_y & upper_limit_y

sliced_x = x[mask_x]
sliced_y = y[mask_y]
```

However if I start with the following data set that spans from approx. 2019-01-23 20:45 to 2019-01-23 04:00:

[image: Original data]

The resulting data seems to be empty. If I do

```
sliced_y.values
```

the result is empty.

How can I successfully slice my data by time stamps?

Comment: I can't replicate, but you may wish to look at [`pd.DataFrame.between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) to filter your dataframe via a single method call.

Comment: Hello @jpp thanks for this tip! I feel like my data is not in the right format right now. E.g. all timestamps are in the `x` series and all values are in the `y` series. How can i merge these two series to have one proper one?

Comment: Is `len(x) == len(y)`, i.e. do your two series have the same length ?

Comment: Yes they do have the same length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a single dataframe, then use the [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) acessor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(y.values, index=x.values)

sliced_df = df.loc['2019-01-23 20:59:04': '2019-01-23 21:37:44']
```

`sliced_df` is now a single dataframe and you can access your `x` and `y` coordinates as follows:

```
sliced_times = sliced_df.index
sliced_values = sliced_df.iloc[:, 0].values
```